# Изменил элемент с помощью CSS инъекции, но как всё вернуть назад?

Tags: css, qt

В общем у меня есть  QProgressBar если я нажимаю на кнопку с надписью "нажимаем" то он меняет вид кнопки используя код реализованный CSS стилем:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->progressBar->setFormat(" неисправен");
    ui->progressBar->setValue(1000);
    ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar{border: 1px solid transparent;text-align: center;"
                                   "color:rgba(255,255,250,255);"
                                   "border-radius: 5px;"
                                   "border-width: 3px;"
                                   "border-image: 9,2,5,2; "
                                   "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 200), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 200));"
                                    "}"
                                   "QProgressBar::chunk {background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 rgba(255,200,0,255), stop: 1 rgba(255,0,0,255));}");
}
```

**ДО**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ПОСЛЕ**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НО ПОСЛЕ Я НАЖИМАЮ НА КНОПКУ "стукаем ",с целью вернуть все назад (как под надписью **ДО**) ,использую такой код :

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
         ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet(QStyle::CE_ProgressBarContents);
         //     ui->progressBar->setStyle(QStyle::CE_ProgressBarContents);
}
```

но он не отрабатывает и выдаёт ошибку:

```
ошибка: no matching function for call to 'QProgressBar::setStyleSheet(QStyle::ControlElement)'
     ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet(QStyle::CE_ProgressBarContents);
```

**ЧТО Я ДЕЛАЮ НЕ ТАК ???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
     ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet(QString());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо заработало :3  /   п.с.  Почему у тебя имя русскими буквами(чёт подозрительно) , ты чё колдун ??